# Xpath in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I need some help with some Xpath. I  have an Xml document I need to shred daily (about 500mb) containing transactions on public transport.

An example of the Xml is shown here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Ov6KXo83pu3xEXGovrFK-Hm2cMjZW1gqwTnRTraj58/edit?usp=sharing

The real file contains hundreds of stops and thousands of transactions.

I have a working stored procedure to shred the document here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tegGjaK0x7L3uajeUlD1ex0F-yoeSueujDTarkW_Bak/edit?usp=sharing

The issue is that when I run it on our VM from Sql Server Agent it takes 5 hours.

Ideally this would be done under an hour (which it does run in on my personal machine).

I thought that maybe I could do something like this and do everything in one statement rather than use temp tables and joining:

```
SELECT
se.value('@Filename', 'varchar(50)') As [Filename], 
se.value('@FareIdentifier', 'varchar(50)') As FareIdentifier,
se.value('@DeviceType', 'varchar(50)') As DeviceType,
ro.value('@ServiceIdentifier', 'varchar(50)') As ServiceIdentifier,
ro.value('@ServiceNumber', 'varchar(50)') As ServiceNumber,
ro.value('@CarrierNumber', 'varchar(50)') AS CarrierNumber,
jo.value('@VehicleRegistration', 'varchar(50)') As VehicleRegistration,
jo.value('@VehicleNumber', 'varchar(50)') As VehicleNumber,
jo.value('@VehicleDepotNumber', 'varchar(50)') As VehicleDepotNumber,
jo.value('@ServiceDepotNumber', 'varchar(50)') As ServiceDepotNumber,
jo.value('@JourneyDirection', 'varchar(50)') As JourneyDirection,
jo.value('@JourneyEnd', 'varchar(50)') As JourneyEnd,
jo.value('@JourneyStart', 'varchar(50)') As JourneyStart,
jo.value('@RunningBoardNumber', 'varchar(50)') As RunningBoardNumber,
jo.value('@RunningBoardDepotNumber', 'varchar(50)') As RunningBoardDepotNumber,
jo.value('@DutyNumber', 'varchar(50)') As DutyNumber,
jo.value('@DutyDepotNumber', 'varchar(50)') As DutyDepotNumber,
jo.value('@DriverName', 'varchar(50)') As DriverName,
jo.value('@DriverNumber', 'varchar(50)') As DriverNumber,
jo.value('@FinalTicketSerial', 'varchar(50)') As FinalTicketSerial,
jo.value('@StartTicketSerial', 'varchar(50)') As StartTicketSerial,
jo.value('@ContractType', 'varchar(50)') As ContractType,
jo.value('@DriverDepotNumber', 'varchar(50)') As DriverDepotNumber,
jo.value('@EtmDepotNumber', 'varchar(50)') As EtmDepotNumber,
jo.value('@Company', 'varchar(50)') As Company,
jo.value('@JourneyType', 'varchar(50)') As JourneyType,
jo.value('@JourneyNumber', 'varchar(50)') As JourneyNumber,
st.value('@TCA', 'varchar(50)') As TCA,
st.value('@Latitude', 'varchar(50)') As Latitude,
st.value('@Longitude', 'varchar(50)') As Longitude,
st.value('@NaptanCode', 'varchar(50)') As NaptanCode,
st.value('@AtcoCode', 'varchar(50)') As ATCOCode,
st.value('@StopName', 'varchar(50)') As StopName,
st.value('@BusStopNumber', 'varchar(50)') As BusStopNumber,
st.value('@StopNumber', 'varchar(50)') As StopNumber,
st.value('@BoardingFareStageName', 'varchar(50)') As BoardingFareStageName,
st.value('@BoardingFareStageNumber', 'varchar(50)') As BoardingFareStageNumber,
st.value('@BoardingFareStageOwner', 'varchar(50)') As BoardingFareStageOwner,
st.value('@RealDeparture', 'varchar(50)') As RealDeparture,
st.value('@RealArrival', 'varchar(50)') As RealArrival,
st.value('@OwnerNumber', 'varchar(50)') As OwnerNumber,
cs.value('@SoldTicketClassName', 'varchar(50)') As SoldTicketClassName,
cs.value('@SalesPrice', 'varchar(50)') As SalesPrice,
cs.value('@PaymentMethod', 'varchar(50)') As PaymentMethod,
cs.value('@ISOCurrency', 'varchar(50)') As ISOCurrency,
cs.value('@SoldTicketClassNo', 'varchar(50)') As SoldTicketClassNo,
cs.value('@TicketProductName', 'varchar(50)') As TicketProductName,
cs.value('@TicketProductNumber', 'varchar(50)') As TicketProductNumber,
cs.value('@NumTransactions', 'varchar(50)') As NumTransactions,
cs.value('@NumPgersOnTicket', 'varchar(50)') As NumPgersOnTicket,
cs.value('@IssueDateTime', 'varchar(50)') As IssueDateTime,
cs.value('@TicketNumber', 'varchar(50)') As TicketNumber,
cs.value('@TicketGUID', 'varchar(50)') As TicketGUID,
cs.value('@DestinationFareStageName', 'varchar(50)') As DestinationFareStageName,
cs.value('@DestinationFareStageNumber', 'varchar(50)') As DestinationFareStageNumber,
cs.value('@DestinationFareStageOwner', 'varchar(50)') As DestinationFareStageOwner,
cs.value('@EventDateTime', 'varchar(50)') As EventDateTime,
cs.value('@TransactionType', 'varchar(50)') As TransactionType,
cs.value('@CardId', 'varchar(50)') As CardId,
cs.value('@SchemeIdentifier', 'varchar(50)') As SchemeIdentifier

FROM
      XMLUpload CROSS APPLY
      XmlData.nodes('Header/Session')   AS [Session](se)        CROSS APPLY
      se.nodes('Routes/Route')          AS [Route](ro)          CROSS APPLY
      ro.nodes('Journey')               As [Journey](jo)        CROSS APPLY
      jo.nodes('DrivenStops/Stop')      As [Stop](st)           CROSS APPLY
      st.nodes('Events/*')      As [CashSale](cs)
```

This does not work as it creates duplicate lines for the elements CashSale and CardUsage (where on one line CashSale fields are null and on one CardUsage fields are null) when they should be part of the same line.

The ideal result is one record for each CashSale which when they exist have the CardUsage fields on the same line. If there is no CardUsage these fields are null.

Could anyone suggest some optimisation or just point me towards some online resource. I'm struggling to find helpful stuff online.

I have already tried changing the data types to be only the size they need to be which gives me some performance but not as much as I need.

I am open to another solution completely (using powershell or similar maybe) but I couldn't get any others to work with this xml.

Answer (score 0):

Such an XML is hard to query. You have to rely on the implicit order. SQL Server's `XQuery` is not fully aware of some fancy navigation stuff like siblings and next elements. But you can do a trick: You can shredd this row-wise within a CTE and use a simple `NodeIndex=NodeIndex+1` to find the next element. If this is called "CardUsage" you take it, otherwise not.

And please: Keep your examples reduced to the minimum!

```
DECLARE @dummyTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, XmlData XML);
INSERT INTO @dummyTable VALUES
 (N'<Header SchemaVersion="2.1" CreationDateTime="20171114044600" ExportCounter="1" DepositDate="20171114" Producer="http://portal.provider.org.uk/v2">
      <Session SessionId="a468dcd3fa963a49b274e64a5c714244" GTCCash="0" GTCRev="0" GTCTrans="0" DepositDateTime="20171112210811" DeviceType="Ticketer ETM" DeviceSerialNumber="0441105106901809" StartDateTime="20171112163000" EndDateTime="20171112210814" FareIdentifier="Ticketer">
        <Routes>
          <Route CarrierNumber="1" ServiceNumber="13" ServiceIdentifier="13">
            <Journey JourneyNumber="639" JourneyType="SRV" Company="1" EtmDepotNumber="188" DriverDepotNumber="188" ContractType="UNK" StartTicketSerial="781" FinalTicketSerial="802" DriverNumber="214373" DutyNumber="214373" RunningBoard="420" JourneyStart="20171112173414" JourneyEnd="20171112190532" JourneyDirection="Outbound" VehicleNumber="67798" VehicleRegistration="67798" DriverName="GARY TAYLOR" VehicleDepotNumber="188" DutyDepotNumber="0" RunningBoardDepotNumber="188" ServiceDepotNumber="0" RunningBoardNumber="3325">
              <DrivenStops>
                <Stop OwnerNumber="1" RealArrival="20171112190057" RealDeparture="20171112190057" BoardingFareStageOwner="0" BoardingFareStageNumber="701" BoardingFareStageName="Town Square (58)" StopNumber="31" BusStopNumber="1" StopName="Town Square" AtcoCode="639001322" NaptanCode="" Latitude="55.165746" Longitude="-2.141343" TCA="">
                  <Events>
                    <CashSale TicketGUID="67177058-d0f8-422e-bb19-9245acea25fa" TicketNumber="802" BoardingFareStageOwner="0" BoardingFareStageNumber="701" BoardingFareStageName="Town Square (58)" DestinationFareStageOwner="0" DestinationFareStageNumber="683" DestinationFareStageName="Golden Lion (60)" IssueDateTime="20171112190057" NumPgersOnTicket="1.00" NumTransactions="1" TicketProductNumber="e8d237e2c67aba4bbc922d8daa46ce75" TicketProductName="SC Over 60" SoldTicketClassNo="18285" ISOCurrency="GBP" PaymentMethod="8" SalesPrice="0" ValuePrice="150" SoldTicketClassName="SC Over 60" />
                    <CardUsage SchemeIdentifier="CCS" CardId="63356000903500039" TransactionType="USAGE" EventDateTime="20171112190057" />
                    <CashSale TicketGUID="f7aa4ed4-a385-407d-b116-1c7eb69563be" TicketNumber="811" BoardingFareStageOwner="0" BoardingFareStageNumber="1421" BoardingFareStageName="Town Square (58)" IssueDateTime="20171112193332" NumPgersOnTicket="1.00" NumTransactions="1" TicketProductNumber="e49ac3fa349bfc40b2173163538c121e" TicketProductName="QR Accept Ad Wk" SoldTicketClassNo="19137" ISOCurrency="GBP" PaymentMethod="15" SalesPrice="0" SoldTicketClassName="QR Accept Ad Wk" />
                    <CardUsage SchemeIdentifier="Barcode" CardId="d66e1bb355df4668b95be2e4764d30a6" TransactionType="USAGE" EventDateTime="20171112193332" />
                    <CashSale TicketGUID="c6c2a867-676a-4d73-98d6-3a2571892b3d" TicketNumber="812" BoardingFareStageOwner="0" BoardingFareStageNumber="1421" BoardingFareStageName="Town Square (58)" IssueDateTime="20171112193336" NumPgersOnTicket="1.00" NumTransactions="1" TicketProductNumber="ed5f87065daf384bab7b0bd9f4b02c80" TicketProductName="Use Wk/M/3M/Yr" SoldTicketClassNo="18724" ISOCurrency="GBP" PaymentMethod="1" SalesPrice="0" SoldTicketClassName="Use Wk/M/3M/Yr" />
                    <CashSale TicketGUID="2c7038ea-0800-4e4e-9d20-35fdb129e317" TicketNumber="828" BoardingFareStageOwner="0" BoardingFareStageNumber="272" BoardingFareStageName="Town Square (58)" DestinationFareStageOwner="0" DestinationFareStageNumber="383" DestinationFareStageName="Long Street (33)" IssueDateTime="20171112204134" NumPgersOnTicket="1.00" NumTransactions="1" TicketProductNumber="38e47af2e0a23c4a85eebd96d419feef" TicketProductName="Adult Single" SoldTicketClassNo="18286" ISOCurrency="GBP" PaymentMethod="1" SalesPrice="250" SoldTicketClassName="Adult Single" />
                  </Events>
                </Stop>
              </DrivenStops>
            </Journey>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Session>
    </Header>');
```

--This is your reduced query:

```
SELECT
st.value('@OwnerNumber', 'varchar(50)') As OwnerNumber,
cs.value('@SoldTicketClassName', 'varchar(50)') As SoldTicketClassName,
--please try to reduce your examples!
cs.value('@TicketGUID', 'varchar(50)') As TicketGUID,
cs.value('@CardId', 'varchar(50)') As CardId

FROM
      @dummyTable AS XmlUpload CROSS APPLY
      XmlData.nodes('Header/Session')   AS [Session](se)        CROSS APPLY
      se.nodes('Routes/Route')          AS [Route](ro)          CROSS APPLY
      ro.nodes('Journey')               As [Journey](jo)        CROSS APPLY
      jo.nodes('DrivenStops/Stop')      As [Stop](st)           CROSS APPLY
      st.nodes('Events/*')      As [CashSale](cs);

/*
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| OwnerNumber | SoldTicketClassName | TicketGUID                           | CardId                           |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1           | SC Over 60          | 67177058-d0f8-422e-bb19-9245acea25fa | NULL                             |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1           | NULL                | NULL                                 | 63356000903500039                |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1           | QR Accept Ad Wk     | f7aa4ed4-a385-407d-b116-1c7eb69563be | NULL                             |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1           | NULL                | NULL                                 | d66e1bb355df4668b95be2e4764d30a6 |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1           | Use Wk/M/3M/Yr      | c6c2a867-676a-4d73-98d6-3a2571892b3d | NULL                             |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1           | Adult Single        | 2c7038ea-0800-4e4e-9d20-35fdb129e317 | NULL                             |
+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
*/
```

--I assume, that you want the `@CardId` besides the `@TicketGUID` - if there is one. Try this:

```
WITH InnerNodesCTE AS
(
    SELECT
    st.value('@OwnerNumber', 'varchar(50)') As OwnerNumber,
    --a running counter
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NodeIndex,
    --the node's name
    cs.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(100)') AS CsNodeName,
    --the node in one piece
    cs.query('.') AS InnerNode

    FROM
          @dummyTable AS XmlUpload CROSS APPLY
          XmlData.nodes('Header/Session')   AS [Session](se)        CROSS APPLY
          se.nodes('Routes/Route')          AS [Route](ro)          CROSS APPLY
          ro.nodes('Journey')               As [Journey](jo)        CROSS APPLY
          jo.nodes('DrivenStops/Stop')      As [Stop](st)           CROSS APPLY
          st.nodes('Events/*')      As [CashSale](cs) 
)
SELECT OwnerNumber,
       InnerNode.value('CashSale[1]/@TicketGUID', 'varchar(50)') As TicketGUID,
       --here you can list all your CashSale attributes
       CardUsageNode.value('CardUsage[1]/@CardId', 'varchar(50)') As CardId
       --here you can list all your CardUsage attributes
FROM InnerNodesCTE AS cs
OUTER APPLY(SELECT cu.InnerNode AS CardUsageNode FROM InnerNodesCTE AS cu WHERE cu.NodeIndex = cs.NodeIndex+1 AND cu.CsNodeName='CardUsage') AS A
WHERE CsNodeName='CashSale'
```

The result

```
/*
+---+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1 | 67177058-d0f8-422e-bb19-9245acea25fa | 63356000903500039                |
+---+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1 | f7aa4ed4-a385-407d-b116-1c7eb69563be | d66e1bb355df4668b95be2e4764d30a6 |
+---+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1 | c6c2a867-676a-4d73-98d6-3a2571892b3d | NULL                             |
+---+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 1 | 2c7038ea-0800-4e4e-9d20-35fdb129e317 | NULL                             |
+---+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
*/
```